# Python random math generator fail

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator

okay i have now encountered a problem with my code, when I run my code it will not give chance for the user to answer

```
print ("what is your username")
name = input () .title()
print (name, "welcome")
import random
score=0
question=0
for i in range(10):

 ops = ["+", "-", "*"]
num1 = random.randint (0,10)
num2 = random.randint (0,10)
oparator = random.choice(ops)
Q=(str(num1)+(oparator)+(str(num2)))
print (Q)


if oparator =='+':
    answer=num1+num2
    if Q == answer:
        print ("correct")
        score=score+1
    else:
         print ("incorrect")


if oparator =='-':
    answer=num1-num2
    if Q == answer:
        print ("correct")
        score=score+1
    else:
         print ("incorrect")


if oparator =='*':
    answer=num1*num2
    if Q == answer:
        print ("correct")
        score=score+1
    else:

        print ("incorrect")
```

i am unsure on how to fix this problem as i am new to programming.
it will not let the user guess and will just print incorrect

```
what is your username
kurt
Kurt welcome
2*0
incorrect
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using int (num1 and num2) and string which comes from ops, fix it like so:

```
input (str(num1)+(ops)+str(num2))
```

In Python you cannot add strings and ints (which is usually not what you want) Python is explicit, so you need to convert your numbers into strings explicitly. It is much more readable that way.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it was helpful?